# how to change state = new OpenState(); in time_elapsed method that reflects changes to state object in memory

Tags: c#

This is method 1

```
  public OpenState(ref State state)
    {
        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(CircuitBreaker.timeout);
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => timer_Elapsed(sender, e, state)); //registering the event handler of timer elapsed            
    }
```

This is method2

```
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, ref State state)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

how to change state = new OpenState(); in time_elapsed method that reflects changes to state object in memory

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Based on the post it looks like you are logging your own answer. Although that's a good practice, that's not how StackOverflow is used. Rather add a bit more details regarding your question to the body of the opening post, then you can add a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't store a reference to a reference, nor can you close on it in a lambda expression.

The simplest option I can think of is to pass a state *container* by value, which can in turn contain an updateable reference to your State instance. Simple example:

```
class ReferenceTo<T>
{
    public ReferenceTo(T source)
    {
        Value = source;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can store your State object in a reference:

```
var state = new ReferenceTo<State>(new State());
```

And you can pass that to the handler, which can update it.

```
void OpenState(ReferenceTo<State> state)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(CircuitBreaker.timeout);
    timer.Start();
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => state.Value = new State());       
}
```

Example call, which shows how to store the State:

```
public void Run()
{
    var state = new ReferenceTo<State>(new State());

    OpenState(state);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss} State is {1}", DateTime.Now, state.Value);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Here is a link to an [example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oiB809) demonstrating that it works.